# Send value from another form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple forms that point to the same site where the datas are stored into a sql database. For each form the user has to fill out a textfield which is separated from the form. I don't understand how i could send for each form the same value from the separated textfield.

```
<form name="user" action="http://hello.xy/login.php" method="GET">
  <input type="text" value="User" name="provider" hidden>
    Name: <br/>
    <input type="text" value="" name="user_name"><br/>
    Email: <br/>
    <input type="text" value= "" name="user_email"><br/>
<textarea hidden name="comment" value="value from the form comment"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<form name="google" action="http://hello.xy/login.php" method="GET">
    <input type="text" value="Google" name="provider" hidden>
  <textarea hidden name="comment" value="value from the form comment"></textarea>
    <input type="image" src="images/logos/google.png" value="submit">
</form>

<form name="twitter" action="http://hello.xy/login.php" method="GET">
    <input type="text" value="Twitter" name="provider" hidden>
  <textarea hidden name="comment" value="value from the form comment"></textarea>
    <input type="image" src="images/logos/twitter.png" value="submit">
</form>

<form name="facebook" action="http://hello.xy/login.php" method="GET">
    <input type="text" value="Facebook" name="provider" hidden>
  <textarea hidden name="comment" value="value from the form comment"></textarea>
    <input type="image" src="images/logos/facebook.png" value="submit">
</form>
```

Separated textfield, but on the same site:

```
<form name="comment" >
    <textarea name="input" ></textarea>
</form>
```

I hope somebody can help me.
Thanks,
Misch

Comment: if you have multiple form on one page so you have to use jquery and ajax for it for ex
<input type="button" onclick="functionname"/>
in jquery
functionname(){
$.ajax(){url:"specified url"}
}
on success you can do what ever you want to do with this click.
Hope it will help for you.

Comment: The correct way to use hidden inputs is `<input type="hidden" name="provider" value="Facebook">`

Comment: Will try with jquery so. Thanks.

Comment: The real question that pops in my mind is: Why do you have to use multiple forms in the first place?

Comment: Because i have different values for each submit form. (different value if i send facebook-form, different value if i send google-form.....) and for each form a separat image for submitting the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't send data from two forms at the same time without JavaScript.

The solution without JavaScript is to use one form:

```
<form action="http://hello.xy/login.php" method="GET">

  <textarea name="comment"></textarea>

  <label for="user_name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name">
  <label for="user_email">Email</label>
  <input type="text" name="user_email" id="user_email">
  <button type="submit" name="provider" value="User">Submit</button>

  <input type="image" src="images/logos/google.png" name="provider" value="Google">
  ...

</form>
```

## Update

Since you're using jQuery, use:

```
<textarea name="comment" class="comment-visible"></textarea>
```

And include this in each form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="comment" class="comment-hidden">
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('input', '.comment-visible', function(){
  $('.comment-hidden').val( $(this).val() );
});
```

Comment: Ok, but thats the problem, i can't use one form :-)

Comment: Looks good, i will try this and post my answer. thank you very much.

Comment: I searched for a solution so long...it worked exactly how you have written it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A `<textarea>` doesn't have a `value=` attribute. The value is the text node inside. ex.

```
<textarea>value</textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you for the input.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.